# SQL ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated - parent key not found

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-02291

I have encountered some problem with SQL foreign key.

Here are my table and insert SQL.

```
create table passenger_card2
(
    phone char(20) primary key,
    name char(20)
);

create table card
(
    card_num char(20) primary key,
    balance number(10,2),
    cvn char(20) 
);

create table passenger_card1
(
    sin integer primary key,
    user_id char(20) not null unique,
    phone char(20),
    card_num char(20) unique,
    foreign key(phone) references passenger_card2,
    foreign key (card_num) references card
);
```

And here are my `INSERT` statements:

```
INSERT INTO PASSENGER_CARD2 VALUES ( '111222333' , 'Ace');
INSERT INTO CARD VALUES ( '1000' , '100.1' , '110');
INSERT INTO PASSENGER_CARD1 VALUES ('100', 'aaaa', '111222333', '1000');
```

However, I get an error when I tried to insert PASSENGER_CARD1 data:

> SQL ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated - parent key not found

I am not sure why my foreign key is wrong?

Comment: Working fine. See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f8df0428ffd9dad948ce25403d51a306)

Comment: As Tejash says it should work. Drop everything and try to insert in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is going to be right but you should make the table 2 first before you create the first table. The database is confused because it wouldnt make sense telling them that theres gonna be a foreign key in the second table but the table isnt created. Run the code for the second table first and then run the code for the first table.

Comment: In my sql statement, the table 1 is after table 2 and table 3... sorry about this confusion.

Comment: drop table passenger_card2 cascade constraints;
drop table card cascade constraints;
drop table passenger_card1 cascade constraints;

create table passenger_card2
(
    phone char(20) primary key,
    name char(20)
);

create table card
(
    card_num char(20) primary key,
    balance number(10,2),
    cvn char(20) 
)

Comment: create table passenger_card1
(
    sin integer primary key,
    user_id char(20) not null unique,
    phone char(20),
    card_num char(20) unique,
    foreign key(phone) references passenger_card2,
    foreign key (card_num) references card );

Comment: INSERT INTO PASSENGER_CARD2 VALUES ( '111222333' , 'Ace');
INSERT INTO CARD VALUES ( '1000' , '100.1' , '110');
INSERT INTO PASSENGER_CARD1 VALUES ('100', 'aaaa', '111222333', '1000');

Comment: Now run all these three code as it is a script and it should work. if it does not work. let me know.